# Images i uploaded on production server is throwing a 404 - Laravel 7

Tags: laravel

I am having issues displaying images i uploaded on my production server, although the images I uploaded on my local server worked just fine. But for some weird reasons, it doesn't work on my production server.

I have created a symlink and executed it, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you create the symlink by running `php artisan storage:link`?

Comment: make you your web user has write permission on your upload folder

Comment: Yes, I did that before I deployed it to my production server.

Comment: Yeah, i did that already. @AnuratChapanond

Comment: when you say you did that before you deployed to your production server, you mean you did that on the production server right?

Comment: @apokryfos, no I mean I did that on my local server.
But, after it didn't work well for the images I uploaded on the production server, I had to create symlink file and execute it on my production server.

Comment: does it throws any exception??did you gave permissions to your storage and public directories?

Comment: @MdSomir no it doesn't throw any exceptions, and yes I have given the user read and write permissions on the storage and public directories.

Comment: I have fixed the bug.
I had to modify config/filesystems.php and change the dir where files are stored.

Thank you guys for the assist!